# How to reduce x ticks in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working on pandas data that has too many time x points/ticks. I have found several solutions to reduce it, but my problem is I'm using two different data set with different time points. So, how to not only reduce the x-ticks as well as aligning these two data time points?
Yes, I know sharex.

My plot generating code is following:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2,ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(4, 1,figsize=(10,7), sharex="all")
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

ax1.plot( df.time, df['B'], color='k')
ax1.plot( df.time, df['Bx'], color='r')
ax1.plot( df.time, df['By'], color='b')
ax1.plot( df.time, df['Bz'], color='g')
ax1.xaxis.grid(True,alpha=0.3)
ax1.set_ylabel('Bx,By,Bz,B[nT]')

ax2.plot(df1.time, df1['v_total'],color='k')
ax2.plot(df1.time, df1['Vx'],color='r')
ax2.plot(df1.time, df1['Vy'],color='b')
ax2.plot(df1.time, df1['Vz'],color='g')
ax2.xaxis.grid(True,alpha=0.3)
ax2.set_ylabel('Vx,Vy,Vz,V[km/s]')

ax3.plot(df1.time, df1['n'],color='k')
ax3.xaxis.grid(True,alpha=0.3)
ax3.set_ylabel('Np[1/cm^3]')

ax4.plot(df1.time, df1['T'],color='k')
ax4.xaxis.grid(True,alpha=0.3)
ax4.set_ylabel('T[k]')
#loc = mdates.MinuteLocator([0,30])
#ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
#ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))
#ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
#ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))
#ax4.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
#ax4.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))
#ax2 = plt.gca()
#ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=10))
#ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')) 
#ax3 = plt.gca()
#ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=10))
#ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')) 
#ax4 = plt.gca()
#ax4.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=10))
#ax4.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')) 

fig.suptitle('Shock format')
plt.savefig('plot.png')
plt.savefig('plot1.pdf')
plt.show()
```

Here df is the one with many points and I want to reduce df x ticks/time points as well as aligning df1 to df. Hashtagged lines are my try, but it takes too long and giving me this warning "Locator attempting to generate 359569 ticks ([-113.5, ..., 2383.5]), which exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS (1000)."

The graph output is following [image: the generated plot]

What my goal should look like is this [image: goal plot]

Comment: Can you provide a graph of the output at this time? And please paste sample data in text.

Comment: Hello, I added my output as well as my goal plot, but I can't upload my data, which is in CSV format. I mean there is no upload section here. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I have created the data as I see fit as it seems difficult to provide data.
The main point is that the `byminute` is the number of minutes, and the default value is 1 minute in the range (60). The interval specifies at what interval that minute increment should be displayed. So for the 15 minute increments, I used `np.range(0,60,15)` and two intervals. The result is 00 and 30 minute increments.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date_rng = pd.date_range('2022-05-31 00:00:00', freq='1s', periods=43200)
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': pd.to_datetime(date_rng), 'value':np.random.randn(43200).cumsum()})

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(4, 1,figsize=(12,6), sharex="all")
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

ax1.plot(df.datetime, df['value'], color='b')
ax2.plot(df.datetime, df['value'], color='g')
ax3.plot(df.datetime, df['value'], color='r')
ax4.plot(df.datetime, df['value'], color='k')

minutes = mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=np.arange(0,60,15),interval=2)
minutes_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d %H:%M')
ax4.xaxis.set_major_locator(minutes)
ax4.xaxis.set_major_formatter(minutes_fmt)

ax4.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: When I run the code, it still says Locator attempting to generate 119857 ticks ([-113.5, ..., 2383.5]), which exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS (1000).
My data is 2 hours with ticks around 57600. Does the minute implementation solve this?

Comment: Probably due to exceeding the limit of the number of scales displayed. Therefore, it is necessary to reduce the number of scales. Even 120 ticks per minute would cause overlap depending on the graph size.

Comment: So, how to reduce the number of scales?

Comment: Here is my two data: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uqmynE78dMM_23ITVBsdu7-5tPbnQ9gC/view?usp=sharing https://drive.google.com/file/d/17kj8MM-agNkS22J5sRGGicdQHCK5EGYL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I ran your code in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QRHUjX7s0RJbToMX0fJFcGgXZ-nyU6Zc?usp=sharing) with your data. The time series data is displayed in the desired format without any additional settings.